# AWS RDS MYSQL SP Privileges Issues (Error Code: 1227)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I have created SP in RDS-MYSQL with the user of abc. Now, I want to update from user xyz but its giving me message: (Note: Both user have full access on db)

Error Code: 1227
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: The _creator_ of the SP and the `SQL SECURITY` don't let you.

Comment: sorry I can't understand your answer. can you explain more.

Comment: Study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html